# Failed to create device file WinEr:000000B7

Tags: c#, dll, usb, hid, kernel32

I'm trying to get Raw Data from USB HID barcode scanner using c# UsbLibrarry.dll, but it fails to create a device file on some computers. I'm using the same barcode scanner, and on other PC is the same OS - Win7, but I don't get any input data. 
Here is some log:

> FindSpecifiedDevice(int vendor_id, int product_id):
>   3118 2311
>
> return new Guid HID 4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030
>
> Initialise(string strPath):
>   \?\hid#vid_0c2e&pid_0907#7&1e9fdc80&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
>
> GenerateWithWinError(string strMessage): Failed to
>   create device file
>
> HIDDeviceException(string strMessage): Msg:Failed to create device
>   file WinEr:000000B7
>
> at UsbLibrary.HIDDevice.Initialise(String strPath) in
>   c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\HIDDevice.cs:line 133
>
> at UsbLibrary.HIDDevice.FindDevice(Int32 nVid, Int32 nPid, Type
>   oType) in c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\HIDDevice.cs:line 265
>
> HIDDeviceException(string strMessage):
>   Msg:UsbLibrary.HIDDeviceException: Msg:Failed to create device file
>   WinEr:000000B7
>
> at UsbLibrary.HIDDevice.Initialise(String strPath) in
>   c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\HIDDevice.cs:line 133
>
> at UsbLibrary.HIDDevice.FindDevice(Int32 nVid, Int32 nPid, Type
>   oType) in c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\HIDDevice.cs:line 265
>
> UsbLibrary.HIDDeviceException:
>   Msg:UsbLibrary.HIDDeviceException: Msg:Failed to create device file
>   WinEr:000000B7
>
> at UsbLibrary.HIDDevice.Initialise(String strPath) in
>   c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\HIDDevice.cs:line 133
>
> at UsbLibrary.HIDDevice.FindDevice(Int32 nVid, Int32 nPid, Type
>   oType) in c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\HIDDevice.cs:line 265
>
> at UsbLibrary.HIDDevice.FindDevice(Int32 nVid, Int32 nPid, Type
>   oType) in c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\HIDDevice.cs:line 273
>
> at UsbLibrary.SpecifiedDevice.FindSpecifiedDevice(Int32 vendor_id,
>   Int32 product_id) in
>   c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\SpecifiedDevice.cs:line 44
>
> at UsbLibrary.UsbHidPort.CheckDevicePresent() in
>   c:\Users\user1\Desktop\UsbLibrary\UsbHidPort.cs:line 234

Here is dll method to create file using kernel32.dll:

```
 private void Initialise(string strPath)
{
  this.m_hHandle = Win32Usb.CreateFile(strPath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
  if (this.m_hHandle != Win32Usb.InvalidHandleValue)
  {
    IntPtr lpData;
    if (!Win32Usb.HidD_GetPreparsedData(this.m_hHandle, out lpData))
      throw HIDDeviceException.GenerateWithWinError("GetPreparsedData failed");
    try
    {
      Win32Usb.HidCaps oCaps;
      Win32Usb.HidP_GetCaps(lpData, out oCaps);
      this.m_nInputReportLength = (int) oCaps.InputReportByteLength;
      this.m_nOutputReportLength = (int) oCaps.OutputReportByteLength;
      this.m_oFile = new FileStream(new SafeFileHandle(this.m_hHandle, false), FileAccess.ReadWrite, this.m_nInputReportLength, true);
      this.BeginAsyncRead();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw HIDDeviceException.GenerateWithWinError("Failed to get the detailed data from the hid.");
    }
    finally
    {
      Win32Usb.HidD_FreePreparsedData(ref lpData);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    this.m_hHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    throw HIDDeviceException.GenerateWithWinError("Failed to create device file");
  }
}
```

Windows is running under user account (on both PC). Also I have tried to add "\.\" to a path, that didn't helped me.

Comment: It is a plain Windows error code.  0xB7 == 183 == ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST, "Cannot create a file when that file already exists".  That is a bit mystifying when you use OPEN_EXISTING, but we can't tell if the error reporting code is correct.  The CreateFile call is suspect, when you specify FILE_SHARE_READ then you demand that nobody else is allowed to write to the device.  That is a pretty tall demand on a HID device, somebody is likely to get ahead of you and opened the device with GENERIC_WRITE access.  So you will be denied access instead.  Add `| FILE_SHARE_WRITE`.

Comment: @Hans Passant , yes, it helped me. Thanks for the answer